# UWP (XAML & C#): Animated CommandBar icon

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-10, win-universal-app

How is it possible to make CommandBar icon animated like in Photos app during syncing photo collection with OneDrive? Should I use a GIF image or there is some better way to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is easy with `Storyboard` defined in xaml:

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="IconRotation" AutoReverse="False" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="360" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)" Storyboard.TargetName="symbolIcon" />
   </Storyboard>
 </Page.Resources>
```

`SymbolIcon`, `AppBarButton` and `CommandBar`:

```
<CommandBar>
  <AppBarButton>
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
     <SymbolIcon x:Name="symbolIcon"  Symbol="Sync" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
       <SymbolIcon.RenderTransform>
          <CompositeTransform/>
       </SymbolIcon.RenderTransform>
      </SymbolIcon>
     </AppBarButton.Icon>
    </AppBarButton>
  </CommandBar>
```

Run it and stop it in cs file:

```
IconRotation.Begin();
IconRotation.Stop();
```

To change **speed of rotation**, change `Duration` property on storyboard and you should be able to reach exactly same animation like in Photo app.

Comment: Thank you very much for your respond. But how can I set this as CommandBar button's icon? I tried to use x:Name="symbolIcon" to desired button but it does not worked for me.

Comment: You're the best - thank you very much! I learned something new.